# Limit number of characters in input type number

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im trying to limit to X number the characters in a input (type of number). ive tried a lot of options and none seems to work. I dont want to use the option tel as it needs the numeric keyboard on a mobile device (yes, with ., and all the symbols) I tried also the pattern solution but it only worked for iOS, didnt work in android (displayed the normal keyboard).

The best way would be that if the user hits the limit dont let him type anymore, if he wants to highlight the text and re-type a different number he is allow to. Just not let him type more than the specified number of characters.

So, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Use `maxlength` property in your `<input>` tag.

Comment: that would be great! if maxLenght would be supported by number type. in HTML5 the input type of number doesnt have this property.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Limit number of characters allowed in form input text field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8545376/limit-number-of-characters-allowed-in-form-input-text-field)

Comment: Not duplicated! I need to be TYPE="NUMBER" not text.

Comment: I stand corrected, not a duplicate.

Comment: @marsalal1014 does your browser supports HTML 5 ?? <input type="number" name="pin" min="1000" max="9999"> this code seems working for me

Comment: it does. Latest Chrome. The problem with that is it doesnt handle if the user stars typing the numbers he want instead using the toggle buttons that comes with the input. if I start typing 1234567789 it will let me put as many numbers as I want

Comment: It will allow you to type as many numbers as you want but if you try to submit the form it will throw an error saying the number has to be within the range you set in the min and max attributes.

Comment: not using a form, is a couple of inputs that do a calculation and throw a result. Calculation is made in the jquery code

Comment: You should look at `oninput` and `onchange` events, so you can trim the input string as needed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Note: [`charCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/charCode) is non-standard and deprecated, whereas [`keyCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode) is simply deprecated.**

Check this code

JavaScript

```
<script>
function check(e,value)
{
    //Check Charater
    var unicode=e.charCode? e.charCode : e.keyCode;
    if (value.indexOf(".") != -1)if( unicode == 46 )return false;
    if (unicode!=8)if((unicode<48||unicode>57)&&unicode!=46)return false;
}
function checkLength()
{
    var fieldLength = document.getElementById('txtF').value.length;
    //Suppose u want 4 number of character
    if(fieldLength <= 4){
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        var str = document.getElementById('txtF').value;
        str = str.substring(0, str.length - 1);
        document.getElementById('txtF').value = str;
    }
}
```

and HTML `input` with `number` type below

```
onInput //Is fired also if value change from the side arrows of field in Chrome browser

<input id="txtF" type="number" onKeyPress="return check(event,value)" onInput="checkLength()" />
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BluAngel/ySt7S/4/)

**Update -- Little bit generic code example**

Change above function into this one

```
function checkLength(len,ele){
  var fieldLength = ele.value.length;
  if(fieldLength <= len){
    return true;
  }
  else
  {
    var str = ele.value;
    str = str.substring(0, str.length - 1);
    ele.value = str;
  }
}
```

In HTML use like this

```
<!-- length 4 -->    
<input id="txtF" type="number" onKeyPress="return check(event,value)" onInput="checkLength(4,this)" />
<!-- length 5 -->    
<input  type="number" onKeyPress="return check(event,value)" onInput="checkLength(5,this)" />
<!-- length 2 -->    
<input  type="number" onKeyPress="return check(event,value)" onInput="checkLength(2,this)" />
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ySt7S/288/)

Comment: It helped me too. Thx @Blu

Comment: Still allows to enter at start and middle, removing the last char.

Comment: @RonaldDsouza Yes because it was not a requirement in question. But if you don't want to allow in start or middle also then see **YashPatel** answer if it can fits on your requirement https://stackoverflow.com/a/22088379/2385565

Comment: @Blu No it doesn't fit. If I input 9999999999(length of 10 numbers), I am still able to press the up arrow and take that digit to 10000000000(11 numbers)

Comment: @RonaldDsouza You can off that spinners by using css. Updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ys1d7xpr/ . Otherwise its better if you start a new question with all your requirements. Your requirements different then the current OP requirement.

Answer (score 7):

Another option - the `tel` input type abides by the `maxlength` and `size` attributes.

```
<input type="tel" size="2" maxlength="2" />
```

```html
<input type="tel" size="10" maxlength="2" />
```

Comment: Yes that would be the best way to go, if, I would need the "." symbols. Its like a weight calculator, the user can enter 123.3 pounds or 123 pounds. If I use "tel" on the mobile devices the keyboard that it will show up is the telephone one, with out "." option.

Answer (score 2):

May be it will be useful.

Here is field to input Patient Age. It allows to input 3 numbers only.

**HTML**

```
<input autocomplete="off" class="form-control"  id="Patient_Age" max="150" maxlength="3" name="PatientAge" placeholder="Age" size="3" type="number" value="0">
```

**JS**

```
<script>
    $(function () {         
        $("#Patient_Age").keydown(function (e) {
            // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, enter  
            if ($(this).val().length <= 2 || $.inArray(e.keyCode, [46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 110]) !== -1 ||
                // Allow: Ctrl+A
                // (e.keyCode == 65 && e.ctrlKey === true) ||
                // Allow: home, end, left, right
                (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 39)) {
                // let it happen, don't do anything
                return;
            }
            else {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
            // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
            if ($(this).val().length <= 2 || (e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
            else {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    }); // end of $

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The HTML5 `number` type input has `min` and `max` attributes.

If you wanted to limit the number of characters to 1 you could set a min of 0 and a max of 9.

You can also set the `step` attribute, which is 1 by default, but would come in use if you wanted the ability to select decimals or other rounded numbers.

```
<input type="number" maxlength="1" max="9" min="1" size="1" />
```

Here's the full **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/bVN8c/)**

Comment: But it doesn't support in all browsers

Comment: that might work, if only the user wont type in the input. Works only if hits the arrow at the end of the input

Comment: As Sarath pointed out the `number` type isn't supported in all browsers. Without using JavaScript (which you could certainly do) the best option might be using `maxlength`, `min` and `max`. Browsers that don't support the `number` type would then fallback to the `text` type and the `maxlength` limit.

Comment: again, this could work only if the user doesnt type the number in the input. you can type as many number as you want

Answer (score 0):

please review this code

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function limitText(limitField, limitCount, limitNum) {
    if (limitField.value.length > limitNum) {
        limitField.value = limitField.value.substring(0, limitNum);
    } else {
        limitCount.value = limitNum - limitField.value.length;
    }
}
</script>

<form name="myform">
<input name="limitedtextfield" type="text" onKeyDown="limitText(this.form.limitedtextfield,this.form.countdown,15);" 
onKeyUp="limitText(this.form.limitedtextfield,this.form.countdown,15);" maxlength="15"><br>
<font size="1">(Maximum characters: 15)<br>
You have <input readonly type="text" name="countdown" size="3" value="15"> characters left.</font>
</form>
```

Comment: thats a good approach, but you see when the extra characters are being removed from the string. I need to prevent/deny the input of more numbers if it has reached the limit.

Comment: once they reached limit they can enter more, it is what  you want

Answer (score 0):

I think this requires the onkeyup event handler.

Use this handler to keep on entering numbers till 5 keyup's are encountered. After this , don't let the the number to be entered by returning a 0, unless key pressed is backspace or delete .

Answer (score 0):

You can try thiss jQuery code :

In HTML

```
<input type="number" id="number" />
```

In JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var element = document.getElementById('number');

    $("#number").keydown(function (event) {
        // Allow only backspace and delete

        if($(this).val().length <= 9 || event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 9 )
        {
            if (event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 9) {
                // let it happen, don't do anything
            } else {
                // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
                if ((event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) && (event.keyCode < 96 || event.keyCode > 105)) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            }
        }else{

            event.preventDefault();
        }          

    });


});
```

I have not any idea wheather its working on IOS N Android but its work on all browser.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xmzJR/1/)

Answer (score 0):

For Decimal values, lets say "25.2" code is as under.

```
if(thisObj.value.indexOf(".") >=0)
{
    if(fieldLength <= 4)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        var str = thisObj.value;
        str = str.substring(0, str.length - 1);
        thisObj.value = str;
    }
}
else
{
    if(fieldLength <= 2)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        var str = thisObj.value;
        str = str.substring(0, str.length - 1);
        thisObj.value = str;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do it like this,

```
<input type="text" pattern="\d*" maxlength="4">
```

Answer (score 0):

Proper way 2020 for type number is to check on keydown validation and it should work like this: `onkeypress="checkValidation(fieldValue);"` <-- on input in html and in js:

```
checkValidation(a) {
    if (`${a}`.length < 8) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the maxlength property like this.

```
<input type="text" maxlength="5"/>
```

Comment: yes, but I need to be type="number" and in html5 it doesnt have this property. I need to be number as I have to get the numeric keyboard in a mobile device.

Comment: Use this link this might be useful to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808184/restricting-input-to-textbox-allowing-only-numbers-and-decimal-point

Answer (score -1):

Dude why go for javascript? Just try

```
<input type="text" maxlength="4" size="4">
```

maxlength  will anyways define a maximum length for the input field.

Hope this solved the problem :)

EDIT: Since you specifically want numbers, why dont you use the above and then run a jquery validation to check for numbers? That will also work..

EDIT: Okay, try

```
<input type="number" name="pin" min="1000" max="9999">
```

Comment: Okay, try    <input type="number" name="pin" min="1000" max="9999">

Answer (score -2):

Did you try the property maxlength ?

```
<input type="text" maxlength="5" name="user" >
```

Comment: yes, but I need to be type="number" and in html5 it doesnt have this property. I need to be number as I have to get the numeric keyboard in  a mobile device.

Comment: is type="number"  will support in all browsers ?

Comment: it seems not all browsers. IE (not surprised), FF(27.0) doesnt have support.

Comment: The OP is asking for an input type of `number`, not `text`.