# input text allow only 3 specific characters

Tags: php, html

Given a text-field that accepts only one character for input, as follows:

```
<input type="text" maxlength="1" name="k1" placeholder="?" />
```

Is it possible to further restrict text input so that only  a `1`, `X` or `2` (like in a betting-system) validates?

Comment: use Javascript for that.

Comment: Can you guide me? Or maybe tell me what to search for, because I have tried for days now :)

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22086823/limit-number-of-characters-in-input-type-number

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<input type="text" max-length="1" name="k1" placeholder="?" pattern="[ABC]" />
```

will allow letters A, B and C. You can replace A,B and C with anything you want

Browser support: http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-pattern

Regex Guide: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two ways to do this, one involves using the pattern attribute, a non-JavaScript solution, that certainly works; see solutions others provide below.  But, if you need to really be more restrictive, here is a JavaScript solution that stops the user in their tracks from submitting invalid data.

HTML:

```
<form>
<label>Enter 1, 2, or x</label>
<input id="myinput" maxlength="1" type="text">
<input type="submit"><input type="reset">
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
myinput.oninput = function() {
  if (myinput.value != 1 && myinput.value != 2 && myinput.value != 'x') {
    alert("Invalid: " + myinput.value);
  }
};
```

Full working example [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ybeeoE)

A good resource that explores the oninput and other events: https://javascript.info/events-change-input

Answer (score 0):

For allowing `1` `2` and `X` , Here

> pattern="[12X]" mean either 1, 2 or X

**Note:** Only `<input type="text" max-length="1" name="k1" pattern="[12X]" />`This will not work until unless you have a form and you submit. This will allow you put any character in input box. This will come in effect when user submit.

```
<form>
    <input type="text" max-length="1" name="k1" pattern="[12X]" />
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```