# Limit number of characters in collection of number input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have used the reference from from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22086823/limit-number-of-characters-in-input-type-number) question and I want to achieve exactly what the question asked however for multiple input text fields. I would like to restrict the user to not type further and have used getElementsByClassName instead of getElementById.

**HTML**

```
   <td>
<input id="quantity_scroll" cart_id="<?php echo $cart_row['id']; ?>" min="1" type ="number" max="99" value="<?php echo $cart_row['quantity'] ;?>" oninput = "checkLength()"  class="form-control form-quantity" style=" width: 60px;text-align: left;" >
</td>
```

**Javascript**

```
function checkLength(){

var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("form-quantity");
var y;
var ele = elements.length/2;

for(y=0; y < ele; y++){
    var length = elements[y].value.length;

      if(length <= 2){

        return true;
    }else{  
            var value = elements[y].value;
             value = value.substring(0, value.length-1);    
             document.getElementsByClassName("form-quantity")[y].value = value;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

However the user is restricted only in the first input box and not in the others. I tried different ways however cannot understand why it isn't happening.

Comment: You could add the `maxlength` attribute to the input?

Comment: "the user is restricted only in the first input box" - I'm not sure if I understand this, do you mean you want restriction to all? or just the first field? because seems to me you need to pass `this` to specifically check the field in focus

Comment: Issue is with your loop... `var ele = elements.length/2;`  and `for(y=0; y < ele; y++){` this loops only once, Which never checks your second item.. Also your code needs more work because it is not working on one input at a time but rather working on all when ever there is a keystroke in any one input element.. you better make  use of the `this` variable within the function and validate only the input element that is triggering the function

Comment: I have divided the length by 2 because I believe because there is another input field which is size. This causes the length to double hence I need to divide it by 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the below code. It will restrict users to not enter more than 3 digit numbers. You just need to ensure that all your input fields have the same class `form-field`:

```js
$(".form-field").on('input', function() {
  var enteredVal = $(this).val();
  if (enteredVal.length > 3) {
    $(this).val(enteredVal.substring(0, enteredVal.length - 1));
    console.log('More than 3 characters not allowed.');
    return;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' class='form-field' />
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it is working perfectly. Although I would like to know what is wrong with my code.

Comment: With JQuery it just gets easier. In traditional JavaScript, as you can see, you had to write lot of code and conditions. Also, this works with dynamic elements as we are using `on`.

Comment: You're Welcome! Happy Coding!

Comment: `Although I would like to know what is wrong with my code. ` this is not explained :)