# How I can make a maximum length in a form?

Tags: html, forms

I made this form:

```
<form>

        Name:<br>
        <input type="text" name="name">

        Last mame:<br>
        <input type="text" name="lastname">

        Email:<br>
        <input type="text" name="email">

        Phone number:<br>
        <input type="text" name="phone">
</form>
```

but I need only 9 numbers in Phone number.

How can i do this?

Then I need a form to chose a color something like this:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Limit number of characters allowed in form input text field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8545376/limit-number-of-characters-allowed-in-form-input-text-field)

Comment: Please split up your question in two separate questions, so it is easier to find someone who has a solution for them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can make a maximum length in a form with the maxlength attribute.

You can see this attribute in the example:

```
<form>
  Phone number:<br>
  <input type="text" name="phone"  maxlength="9" >
</form>
```

2.You can make a form to chose the color with input type: color

```
<form>
  Color:
  <input type="color" name="color">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks you very much