# limit imput length to max 10 chars

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to limit a form of input to 10 chars

```js
var max_chars = 10;

$('input#ctl00$bc$custom_element_44').keydown( function(e){
    if ($(this).val().length >= max_chars) { 
        $(this).val($(this).val().substr(0, max_chars));
    }
});

$('input#ctl00$bc$custom_element_44').keyup( function(e){
    if ($(this).val().length >= max_chars) { 
        $(this).val($(this).val().substr(0, max_chars));
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="ctl00$bc$custom_element_44" type="text" id="ctl00_bc_custom_element_44">
```

But it does not seem to work, advice is sought;)

Regards Pete

Comment: `<input type="text" maxlength="10">`

Comment: `$('input#ctl00$bc$custom_element_44')` this ID is wrong. You need `$('#ctl00_bc_custom_element_44')`.

Comment: @evolutionxbox is right, you're targetting the `name` attribute instead of the `id` attribute.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8545376/limit-number-of-characters-allowed-in-form-input-text-field

Comment: @trincot mark dupe only covers JS ways and is not exact dupe. Please see dupe in my previous comment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simplest approach, vanilla JavaScript. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yh18rqt1/).

JS:

```
let name = document.getElementById('name');

name.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
    if (name.value.length > 10) {
        name.value = name.value.slice(0, 10);
    }
})
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="name">
```

Comment: thanks, works perfect

Comment: Sure! I'll leave it as an exercise to you to convert it to jQuery if that's what you want to use. Should be more or less the same, just changing syntax.

Answer (score 2):

You can use native `maxlength` attribute on the `input` tag.

```
<input name="ctl00$bc$custom_element_44" type="text" id="ctl00_bc_custom_element_44" maxlength="10">
```

Comment: Thanks, but I can not edit directly in the input field

Answer (score -3):

Use below code

var max_chars = 10;

    $('#ctl00_bc_custom_element_44').keydown(function(e) {
      if ($(this).val().length >= max_chars) {

        $(this).val($(this).val().substr(0, max_chars));
      }
    });
    $('#ctl00_bc_custom_element_44').keyup(function(e) {

      if ($(this).val().length >= max_chars) {

        $(this).val($(this).val().substr(0, max_chars));
      }
    });

or use max length with input tag

Comment: Format your code please