# Php $_Post doesn't work after certain length imput

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I have a form

```
<form action="welcome.php" method="post" ........................">

      <button id=......................ERATE NEW ....</button>
      <br/><br/>
      <div class="form-field">
        <label for...............">....... TEST</label>
        <br/>
        <textarea id=...........................="false"></textarea>
        <span class="clipSp............ successfully copied to clipboard" ></span>
        <br/>
      </div>
      <br/>

      <div clas..........content">
        <div>ADDRESS
          <br/>
          <span>{{vm.displayAddress}}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="wButton fade" type="submit">REGISTER ACCOUNT</button>
      <span class="divider-2"></span>
      <button class="wButton fade" type="reset" ng-click="vm.back()">BACK</button>
      .
      .
      .
      .
```

Then i have this "welcome.php" file.

```
if(!empty($_POST['formdesiredpost'])){
    $var  = $_POST['formdesiredpost'];
    file_put_contents("dat‌​a.txt", $var . "\n", FILE_APPEND); 
    header("Location: https://randomwebsiteredirect.com"); 
    exit();
}
```

Its supposed to post the desired value from the form **(textarea)** into a txt file, `data.txt` and then redirect to a website.
The problem is that it only works for short length inputs. I mean `aprox (15 characters)` , if I input more than `15 , like 70,` it simply redirects to blank welcome.php and does nothing.

Any clue of what may be happening?

Answer (score 0):

On your html you don't have the "formdesiredpost" field. Please check does there exist "formdesiredpost" field.

And in your welcome.php, on the top side of your code add error reporting function:

`error_reporting(0);`

To see what happened after send data to welcome.php

Works fine:

index.php:

```
<form action="welcome.php" method="post">
<textarea name="formdesiredpost"></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

welcome.php

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['formdesiredpost'])){
    $var  = $_POST['formdesiredpost'];
    file_put_contents("data.txt", $var . "\n", FILE_APPEND); 
    header("Location: https://randomwebsiteredirect.com"); 
    exit();
}
?>
```

And please check your character limits of fields:
[Limit number of characters allowed in form input text field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8545376/limit-number-of-characters-allowed-in-form-input-text-field)