# Regular expression for number with digit length limit including decimal

Tags: jquery, regex, validation, input

I am having an issue while I am validating a textbox with number upto 11 digits including decimal and two digits after decimal(if any). On keyup in jquery.

I used this regular expression **/^(\d+)?([.]?\d{0,2})?$/g** to validate for a number and decimal with two digits, but I do not know how to constraint digits max to 11.

I have used the input **type number** with **maxlength** but it's not working.

[**Fiddle Is here**](http://jsfiddle.net/wikijames/ntywf/2646/)

**Html**

```
<input type="number" />
```

**jQuery**

```
 $('input').keyup(function() {
        var $th = $(this);
        $th.val( $th.val().match(/^(\d+)?([.]?\d{0,2})?$/g, 
        function(str) { 
          return ''; }
          ) );
    });
```

Values like this

> 64123841.33 123456789.1 ,  12345678901, 
>   1.22,

Please Help me out with this.

Comment: Could you give some examples of valid and invalid values. For example, would `12345678901.11` be valid?

Comment: total 11 digits or 11 digits before decimal point

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan like 123456789.1 , 12345678901, 1.22

Comment: [*Some people, when confronted with a problem, think “I know, I'll use regular expressions.”  Now they have two problems.* - Jamie Zawinski](http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247)

Comment: So, you want to set a limit to the overall text length. Why not use [`maxlength="11"`](http://jsfiddle.net/tfqaj8zs/)?

Comment: Dupe of [Limit number of characters allowed in form input text field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8545376/limit-number-of-characters-allowed-in-form-input-text-field).

Comment: onkeyup is not appropriate.  There are other ways to fill out forms.  Autocomplete, drag&drop, paste.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
^\d{0,8}\.\d{1,2}$|^\d{0,11}$
```

[here](https://regex101.com/r/ufC8kn/4/) is the working example

Comment: Look at your regex101 example again. Its not really matching as it should. It matches `3123123` as one match,`.` as one, and `22` as one.

Comment: @Olian04 now checking only once

Answer (score 1):

use a lookahead to test the length:

```
/^(?=.{1,11}$)\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?$/
```

`(?=.{1,11}$)` is a lookahead that make sure we have 1 up to 11 character

`(?:\.\d{1,2})?` is an optional non capture group that allows 1 or 2 decimal

Comment: Why not `maxlength="11"`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Because OP wants a regex. But, of course, attribute `maxlength="11"` is another solution.