# Limit number of characters allowed in a form input after a specific charcater

Tags: html, forms, input, textbox

There are many ways to limit the number of characters, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8545376/limit-number-of-characters-allowed-in-form-input-text-field). In my case I want to limit the number of characters introduced after a dot.

I've tried to compute this inside `maxlength`:

```
myNumber = 43.143;

maxlength = (myNumber.Length - myNumber.IndexOf(".") - 1) <= 2;
```

Comment: Are you planning to display this length

Comment: I'm planning to limit the number of characters that can be introduced after the dot to 2.

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to display this variable. You can use .toFixed()

For example

```
example.textContent = myNumber.toFixed(2);
```

This would limit the number of decimal points to two on a display cancelling the need for editing it in your variable.

If this helped you please select this as the correct answer!

Cheers!

Comment: it doesn't work. for example, it modifies all values to have 2 digits after the dot, even if it doesn't have any