# limit characters in input form with javascript

Tags: javascript, input

I want to limit the number of characters from 3 to 10 in an input form. How can I manage it using Javascript. I need to do it with Javascript so I can change the input field border color from black to red when user's input doesn't meet the requirements. Here is my HTML code. I have tried some variants but got into a mess. Please provide me with the simple solution. Thanks beforehand.

```
<form action="/index" method="POST">
  <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="First name">
  <br>
  <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" placeholder="Last name">
</form>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Limit number of characters allowed in form input text field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8545376/limit-number-of-characters-allowed-in-form-input-text-field)

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this;

```
<input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" placeholder="Last name" minlength="3" maxlength = "10">
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `maxlength` and `minlength`:

```
<form action="/index" method="POST">
  <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="First name" minlength="3" maxlength="10">
</form>
```